# YouTube Api v3 handling Exceptions in Python

Tags: python, youtube-api

I am using Youtube API v3 with python and I am encountering a problem when making a search of a video that does not  exist. I am using the following code:

```
 while True:
        try:
            print "Call Search API..."
            youtube = get_authenticated_service()
            search_response = youtube.search().list(
            part="id,snippet",
            maxResults=options.maxResults,
            type = "video",         
            relatedToVideoId = options.q,
            videoType="movie"
            ).execute()

            break
        except:               
            print "Failed to connect to API - Retry.."
```

With this code I am handling situations where the network is unstable and needs some seconds to start again but when I am locating a videos, e.g HFpy1nma2E, that does not exist the while loop runs eternally. Can some one suggest me a more sophisticated exception to handle this kind of problem?

Thank you in advavance.

Comment: You should catch different types of errors, and handle them differently. I'd also add a time delay upon exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The example for uploading a video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#upload_video) gives a good idea of which types of Exceptions might be raised by the client library. As the commenter suggested, you need to explicitly different subclasses of Exception to avoid catching every possible error.